# NSDictionary count all children

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have the following **NSDictionary** structure:

```
// level
0    1    2    3

// elements
a1 - b1 - c1 - d111.1
             - d111.2
             - d111.3
          c2 - d112.1
             - d112.2
          c3 - d113.1
```

Considering that the data file will be round 2000-5000 elements. What is a quick way of counting **only** the children on level 3 (a1=0)? To be clear: I **don't** want to include in the count: a1,b1,c1-c3, only d*.

Is this something you could do with NSPredicate?

Or a old fashioned (but expensive) for-loop approach (eeks) ?

```
// pseudo-code
count=0
for (a in root)
 for (b in a)
   for (c in b)
     for (d in c)
       count++
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's like a tree, you need a BFS where you stop at level 3.

Comment: I don't see how the for-loop could be more expensive than a predicate, which will do the same thing but wrapped in a fancy manner.

Comment: It can get a little simpler by just summing the `count` values of the innermost dicts, rather than walking them.

Comment: Where are the dictionaries? Are all of these dictionaries? What does `d113.1` refer to—a dictionary, or a key in a dictionary `d113`? If `d113` and its siblings are the dictionaries, do you want to count the dictionaries themselves or total up the numbers of keys in them?

Comment: The root is a dict, from there it contains *NSArray of NSDictionaries*, up to 5 levels.  The d111 is means nothing (111 is from a1,b1,c1). I'm after the quickest way to count all children of the last level (this example its lvl 3)

Answer (score 1):

As @Hot states:

```
int count = 0;
   for (NSArray *a in root)
      for (NSArray *b in a)
         for (NSArray *c in b)
            count += c.count;
```

There is really not that much overhead to just slog through the levels up to the last and then just use the count.

Comment: That works if `root` is an array of arrays of arrays. There are no dictionaries there. For the questioner's problem, where at least one of the levels is dictionaries, you will need to send `objectForKey:` at some point (assuming none of the keys are enumerable), or use `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is ill defined.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using categories.

```
@implementation NSDictionary (RecursiveCount)
- (NSUInteger)recursiveCount {
    return self.allValues.recursiveCount;
}
@end

@implementation NSArray (RecursiveCount)
- (NSUInteger)recursiveCount {
    int count = 0;
    for (id object in self) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] || [object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            count += [object recursiveCount];
        } else {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
@end
```

---

```
- (void)testRecursiveCount {
    NSDictionary *dict = @{
                           @"key1" : @[@1, @2, @3],
                           @"key2" : @{@"blah" : @[@[], @1, @[@1, @2]]},
                           @"key3" : @4,
                           @"key5" : @[@{@"blah":@[@{@1:@1}]}],
                           };
    XCTAssertEqual(dict.recursiveCount, 8, @"dictionary");

    NSArray *array = @[
                       @[@1, @2, @3],
                       @{@"blah" : @[@[], @1, @[@1, @2]]},
                       @4,
                       @[@{@"blah":@[@{@1:@1}]}],
                       ];
    XCTAssertEqual(array.recursiveCount, 8, @"dictionary");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use recursion.  This approach is not the cheapest, but it does have the advantage of flexibility--if the depth of the structure changes or is unknown at compile time.

In psuedocode:

```
integer count ( collection , maxDepth )
    return recursiveCount ( collection , 0 , maxDepth )
end

integer recursiveCount ( collection , currentDepth , maxDepth )
    integer count = 0
    if collection is array
        count += recursiveCountArray ( collection , currentDepth , maxDepth )
    else if object is dictionary
        count += recursiveCountDictionary ( collection.values , currentDepth , maxDepth )
    else
        count += 1
    return count
end

integer recursiveCountArray ( array , currentDepth , maxDepth )
    integer count = 0
    if currentDepth < maxDepth
        for ( object in array )
            count += recursiveCount( object )
    else
        count += array.count
    return count
end
```

The `maxDepth` parameter ensures that no more work than necessary is done (simply returning the count of the array when at the maxDepth rather than iterating over the array and adding incrementing the count by one on each iteration as @RamyAlZuhouri suggested in his comment).

In Objective-C, this could be achieved with C functions:

```
static NSUInteger _PFXRecursiveCount(id collection, NSUInteger currentDepth, NSUInteger maxDepth);
static NSUInteger _PFXRecursiveCountArray(id array, NSUInteger currentDepth, NSUInteger maxDepth);

NSUInteger PFXRecursiveCount(id collection, NSUInteger maxDepth)
{
    return _PFXRecursiveCount(collection, 0, maxDepth);
}

NSUInteger _PFXRecursiveCount(id collection, NSUInteger currentDepth, NSUInteger maxDepth)
{
    NSUInteger count = 0;
    if ([collection isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        count = _PFXRecursiveCountArray(collection, currentDepth, maxDepth);
    } else if ([collection isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)collection;
        count = _PFXRecursiveCountArray(dictionary.allValues, currentDepth, maxDepth);
    } else {
        count = 1;
    }
    return count;
}

NSUInteger _PFXRecursiveCountArray(NSArray *array, NSUInteger currentDepth, NSUInteger maxDepth)
{
    NSUInteger count = 0;
    if (currentDepth < maxDepth) {
        for (id object in array) {
            count += _PFXRecursiveCount(object, currentDepth + 1, maxDepth);
        }
    } else {
        count += array.count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here `PFX` would be replaced with the appropriate prefix that is being used in your project.  Only `PFXRecursiveCount` would be declared in the header.

Alternatively, this could be achieved with blocks:

```
typedef NSUInteger (^RecursiveCountArrayBlock)(NSArray *, NSUInteger, NSUInteger);
typedef NSUInteger (^RecursiveCountBlock)(id, NSUInteger, NSUInteger);

__block __weak RecursiveCountArrayBlock _weakRecursiveCountArray = nil;
__block __weak RecursiveCountBlock _weakRecursiveCount = nil;

NSUInteger (^_recursiveCount)(id, NSUInteger, NSUInteger) = ^(id collection, NSUInteger currentDepth, NSUInteger maxDepth) {
    NSUInteger count = 0;
    if ([collection isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        count = _weakRecursiveCountArray(collection, currentDepth, maxDepth);
    } else if ([collection isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)collection;
        count = _weakRecursiveCountArray(dictionary.allValues, currentDepth, maxDepth);
    } else {
        count = 1;
    }
    return count;
};
_weakRecursiveCount = _recursiveCount;

NSUInteger (^_recursiveCountArray)(id, NSUInteger, NSUInteger) = ^(NSArray *array, NSUInteger currentDepth, NSUInteger maxDepth) {
    NSUInteger count = 0;
    if (currentDepth < maxDepth) {
        for (id object in array) {
            count += _weakRecursiveCount(object, currentDepth + 1, maxDepth);
        }
    } else {
        count += array.count;
    }
    return count;
};
_weakRecursiveCountArray = _recursiveCountArray;

NSUInteger (^recursiveCount)(id, NSUInteger) = ^(id collection, NSUInteger maxDepth) {
    return _recursiveCount(collection, 0, maxDepth);
};
```

The `__weak` `__block` variables (`_weakRecursiveCountArray` and `_weakRecursiveCount`) allow us to avoid a strong reference to the block from within itself.  (*Note*: prior to iOS 5 and 10.7, `__weak` would need to be replaced with `__unsafe_unretained`.)  The typedefs allow us to avoid a spurious warning ("'__weak' only applies to objective-c object or block pointer types; type here is 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')").